# relative position button not aligning all the way to the right

Tags: html, css, css-position

```css
.clearfix::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.header {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.content h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.content p {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.button {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header class="header ">
  <div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="content ">
      <h1>left</h1>
      <p>right</p>
      <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Trying to set position of the button all the way top, right within the "wrap" div. As seen in jsfiddle, its being stopped by the text it looks like. So it doesn't light up properly, should be above the text all the way to the right, it is z-index 1. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `position: absolute` to the button and `position: relative` to the container.

```css
.clearfix::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.header {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.content h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.content p {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0px;
  clear: both;
}

.button {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header class="header ">
  <div class="wrap clearfix">
    <div class="content ">
      <h1>left</h1>
      <p>right</p>
      <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Can you explain why this works? I am completely confused about positions... What is container relative to and how is absolute position set and button stays within the container?

Comment: read this short article about css positioning https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/